# Remember path over session in QFileDialog

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Whenever my application is restarted, the open dialog always points to the tool location.

It would be much more useful if it pointed to the last location used for loading files.

I tried setting **environment variable** but it still opens the dialog with current dir path

**code:**

```
def openFile():
    last_path = os.environ.get('LAST_PATH')  # if 'LAST_PATH' doesn't exist return None
    path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open text file", dir=last_path) 
    os.environ["LAST_PATH"] = os.path.dirname(path) # save path from where file is opened in QFileDialog to 'LAST_PATH'

    *other code*
```

Above code is not working as i expected. Why ? 
Is environment variable set through python script exist till that application is not closed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qsettings format of Pyside

```
def openFile():
    settings = QSettings("Company name", "Application name")
    last_path = settings.value("LAST_PATH", ".")
    path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open text file", dir=last_path)
    self.settings.setValue("LAST_PATH", os.path.dirname(path))
```

Answer (score 3):

i can suggest you to take a look to the QSettings 
http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QSettings.html.
I can provide you an example on how to use QSettings with pyqt, i never try pySide, but i think it's quite similar.

First you need to read the QSettings when you start your application. So create a QSetting 
object and then read the parameter named "last_file". At the first run of your program,
this variable is not existing, so it will return "." which is the tool directory

```
settings = QSettings()
last_file_opened = settings.value("last_file", ".").toString()
```

When you choose your file you have to add this code.

```
settings = QSettings()
settings.setValue("last_file", QVariant(QString('file_name')))
```

Also it's important to set this parameters when you create the QApplication. This create a space in the memory where the settings will be saved

```
app = QApplication(argv)
app.setOrganizationName("yourOrg")
app.setOrganizationDomain("yourOrgDomain")
app.setApplicationName("yourApplicationName")
```

I hope it help

Comment: In your code will 'last_file' will retain value when i restart the application ?

Comment: "last_file" it's just the name of a particular setting. In my example i use it to store the name of the last file opened in a previous run. When i restart the program, it will check if in the setting "last_file" there is a file_name. If there is it will be saved in the last_file_opened variable. By the way in "last_file" you have the name of the last file opened

Answer (score 2):

Try it with saving your path into a file, which will be in this example located in the directory of your script.

```
def openFile():
    with open("directory_file.txt","rU") as openfile:
        last_path = openfile.read()
    path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open text file", dir=last_path)
    with open("directory_file.txt","w") as openfile:
        openfile.write(str(path)) # Common use to maek str(), because QFiledialog returns a Qstring
    <DoYourProcessing>
```

For using this function, you have to create a "directory_file.txt" file in the directory of your source code. You could do it either manually with your Notepad(++) Editor, or by this piece of code:

```
def write_file(directory,string_to_write):
    with open(str(directory),"w") as openfile:
        openfile.write(string_to_write)
```

That you haven't initialised the environment variable before could also be the reason that your code didn't work.
Furthermore, it is rather unconvenient  to use environment variables for tiny things like this.

Comment: Is it worth to maintain path in a new file for this tiny thing ?

Comment: I'm sorry for my english. This was my fault to express it that way. 
When Setting environment variables, then these are a kind of global variables. And it is often said to keep it as local as possible and as global as necessairy. Furthermore it is usual practice to save your settings in a file. You could expand the whole Idea, and pickle all your settings object to a file. Whan recalling the program, just unpickle the file and *ThereYouGo* all the settings of the previous session restored.